# Extracting data from a file using regular expressions and storing in a list to be compiled into a dictionary- python

Tags: python

I've been trying to extract both the species name and sequence from a file as depicted below in order to compile a dictionary with the key corresponding to the species name (FOX2_MOUSE for example) and the value corresponding to the Amino Acid sequence.

Sample fasta file:

```
>sp|P58463|FOXP2_MOUSE
MMQESATETISNSSMNQNGMSTLSSQLDAGSRDGRSSGDTSSEVSTVELL
HLQQQQALQAARQLLLQQQTSGLKSPKSSEKQRPLQVPVSVAMMTPQVIT
PQQMQQILQQQVLSPQQLQALLQQQQAVMLQQQQLQEFYKKQQEQLHLQL
LQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ-HPGKQAKE
QQQQQQQQQ-LAAQQLVFQQQLLQMQQLQQQQHLLSLQRQGLISIPPGQA
ALPVQSLPQAGLSPAEIQQLWKEVTGVHSMEDNGIKHGGLDLTTNNSSST
TSSTTSKASPPITHHSIVNGQSSVLNARRDSSSHEETGASHTLYGHGVCK
>sp|Q8MJ98|FOXP2_PONPY
MMQESVTETISNSSMNQNGMSTLSSQLDAGSRDGRSSGDTSSEVSTVELL
HLQQQQALQAARQLLLQQQTSGLKSPKSSDKQRPLQVPVSVAMMTPQVIT
PQQMQQILQQQVLSPQQLQALLQQQQAVMLQQQQLQEFYKKQQEQLHLQL
LQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ--HPGKQAKE
QQQQQQQQQ-LAAQQLVFQQQLLQMQQLQQQQHLLSLQRQGLISIPPGQA
ALPVQSLPQAGLSPAEIQQLWKEVTGVHSMEDNGIKHGGLDLTTNNSSST
TSSTTSKASPPITHHSIVNGQSSVLNARRDSSSHEETGASHTLYGHGVCK
```

I've tried using my code below:

```
import re
InFileName = "foxp2.fasta"
InFile = open(InFileName, 'r')
Species = []
Sequence = []
reg = re.compile('FOXP2_\w+')
for Line in InFile:
    Species += reg.findall(Line)
print Species
reg = re.compile('(^\w+)')
for Line in Infile:
    Sequence += reg.findall(Line)
print Sequence
dictionary = dict(zip(Species, Sequence))
InFile.close()
```

However, my output for my lists are:

[FOX2_MOUSE, FOXP2_PONPY]

[]

Why is my second list empty? Are you not allowed to use re.compile() twice? Any suggestions on how to circumvent my problem?

Thank you,

Christy

Comment: Doesn't biopython already have all the necessary code for fasta anyway?

Comment: If you're dealing with fasta files, you may wish to consider using http://biopython.org/ which has a myriad of tools for parsing/processing fasta data...

Comment: I know it's possible, but I wanted to try it without biopython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read a file twice, you have to seek back to the beginning.

```
InFile.seek(0)
```

Comment: Correct answer. The first loop has move the file pointer to the end of the file. And a simple `seek` can move it to the begin of the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single pass, and without regular expressions:

```
def load_fasta(filename):
    data     = {}
    species  = ""
    sequence = []
    with open(filename) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith(";"):    # is comment?
                # skip it
                pass
            elif line.startswith(">"):  # start of new record?
                # save previous record (if any)
                if species and sequence:
                    data[species] = "".join(sequence)
                species = line.split("|")[2]
                sequence = []
            else:                       # continuation of previous record
                sequence.append(line)

        # end of file - finish storing last record
        if species and sequence:
            data[species] = "".join(sequence)
    return data

data = load_fasta("foxp2.fasta")
```

On your given file, this produces `data ==`

```
{
    'FOXP2_PONPY': 'MMQESVTETISNSSMNQNGMSTLSSQLDAGSRDGRSSGDTSSEVSTVELLHLQQQQALQAARQLLLQQQTSGLKSPKSSDKQRPLQVPVSVAMMTPQVITPQQMQQILQQQVLSPQQLQALLQQQQAVMLQQQQLQEFYKKQQEQLHLQLLQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ--HPGKQAKEQQQQQQQQQ-LAAQQLVFQQQLLQMQQLQQQQHLLSLQRQGLISIPPGQAALPVQSLPQAGLSPAEIQQLWKEVTGVHSMEDNGIKHGGLDLTTNNSSSTTSSTTSKASPPITHHSIVNGQSSVLNARRDSSSHEETGASHTLYGHGVCK',
    'FOXP2_MOUSE': 'MMQESATETISNSSMNQNGMSTLSSQLDAGSRDGRSSGDTSSEVSTVELLHLQQQQALQAARQLLLQQQTSGLKSPKSSEKQRPLQVPVSVAMMTPQVITPQQMQQILQQQVLSPQQLQALLQQQQAVMLQQQQLQEFYKKQQEQLHLQLLQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ-HPGKQAKEQQQQQQQQQ-LAAQQLVFQQQLLQMQQLQQQQHLLSLQRQGLISIPPGQAALPVQSLPQAGLSPAEIQQLWKEVTGVHSMEDNGIKHGGLDLTTNNSSSTTSSTTSKASPPITHHSIVNGQSSVLNARRDSSSHEETGASHTLYGHGVCK'
}
```

Comment: The difference between answering the question, and solving the problem. Never have I seen it so starkly demonstrated.

Comment: haha. Thank you both. It's also nice to see another view on how to write my code with a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in a single pass with a multiline regex:

```
import re
reg = re.compile('(FOXP2_\w+)\n(^[\w\n-]+)', re.MULTILINE)
with open("foxp2.fasta", 'r') as file:
    data = dict(reg.findall(file.read()))
```

The downside is that you have to read the whole file in at once. Whether this is a problem depends on likely file sizes.